# If $ X_n \ \xrightarrow{d}\ X$, then $\lim_n P(X_n\in [a,b]) = P(X\in [a,b])$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of real-valued random variables that converge in distribution to some $X$. Let $a<b\in \mathbb R$. Is is true that $\lim_n P(X_n\in [a,b]) = P(X\in [a,b])$
>    ?

I'd like to argue that $P(X_n\in [a,b]) = E(\mathbb 1_{[a,b]}(X_n))$. However, $x\mapsto \mathbb 1_{[a,b]}(x)$ is bounded, but not continuous, so I cannot apply the well-known property of convergence in distribution.

Comment: Glad it helped, I moved it to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Migrated from comment)*

This is not true in general. A simple counter-example is $[a, b] = [0, 1]$ with the sequence of constant random variables $X_n = -\frac{1}{n}$ that converge to $X = 0$  ($\mathbb{P}$-a.s. and hence in distribution). On the other hand, it is true when $X$ has a continuous distribution.

A more general statement is part of the [*Portmanteau theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures).

Comment: Just one thing, as I don't have time to sift through the terminology of the theorem (weak convergence and all that) at the moment. When the distribution of $X$ is continuous, I can prove the statement for intervals by resorting on the theorem of convergence for cdf's (which seems to be a consequence of Portmanteau theorem). However, with a continuous distribution still, will it still hold true that $\lim_n P(X_n\in A) = P(X\in A)$ for any measurable $A$ ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon, Without regularity of the set we cannot expect much. As a counter-example, consider $X_n$ having the discrete uniform distribution over the set $\{k/2^n : 0 \leq k < 2^n\}$. Then $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ having the uniform distribution over $[0, 1]$, but if we choose $A = \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ as the set of irrational numbers then $\mathbb{P}(X_n \in A) = 0$ while $\mathbb{P}(X \in A) = 1$.